# Is there something wrong with my variables?

Tags: php, forms, image, upload

I was going through some tutorial on Youtub

Of course I made a few changes to suit my needs.

I ended up with the code below.

The HTML form:

```
<form action="include/gallery-upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
<input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$_SESSION["id"].'">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The PHP script:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /* Set some variables */
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
    $newFileTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $newFileDescription = $_POST['description'];
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $originalFileName = $file['name'];
    $originalFileType = $file['type'];
    $originalFileTemp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $originalFileError = $file['error'];
    $originalFileSize = $file['size'];

    /* Check if filename is empty */
    if(empty($newFileName)){
        $newFileName = "img";
    }
    else{
        $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
    }

    /* Check file extension is permitted */
    $fileExt = explode(".", $newFileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "jfif", "png", "gif");
    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=fileTypeNotPermitted");
        exit();
    }
    /* Check for file error */
    elseif($originalFileError === 0){
        header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=fileErrorDetected");
        exit();
    }
    /* Check for file size */
    elseif($originalFileSize > 2097152){
        header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=fileTooLarge");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        /* Create new file name */
        $imgNewFullName = $userid."-".$newFileName."-".uniqueid("", true).".".$fileActualExt;
        /* File destination */
        $fileDestination = "../pix/gallery/".$imgNewFullName;
        /* Include connection to gallery database */
        require_once 'dbh.gallery.inc.php';
        if( empty($newFileTitle) || empty($newFileDescription) ){
            header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=inputEmpty");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            /* Get all from picture table, to count rows */
            $sql = "select * from picture;";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=sqlSelectFailed");
                exit();
            }
            else{
                mysqli_stmt_exec($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $setImgOrder = $rowcount + 1;
                /* INSERT IMAGE INTO DATABASE */
                $sql = "insert into picture (title, description, imgFileName, orderInGallery) values (?, ?, ?, ?);";
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=sqlInsertFailed");
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    /* Insert picture with associated data into database */
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $newFileTitle, $newFileDescription, $imgNewFullName, $setImgOrder);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    move_uploaded_file($originalFileTemp, $fileDestination);
                    header("location: ../gallery.php?uimessage=imgUploadedSuccessfully");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've fiddled around with it extensively, but I keep getting the "fileErrorDetected", which I have on line 35 of the PHP script.

I **think** it's because of my variable names passing the POST data down through the script, but I'm uncertain exactly what I've done to screw it up.

BTW, the reason I've included the user ID as a hidden form input is to prepend it as a prefix on image file names, to use later in ordering and filtering and such.

Anyway, I am an admitted noob, so would greatly appreciate it if anyone can spot my screw-up.

Comment: Error 0 -> *Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.* so I think `$originalFileError === 0` isn't what you are after!

Comment: That's because this tutorial is absolute trash. apart from that, what are you trying to achieve with this condition, `elseif($originalFileError === 0){` exactly?

Comment: "BTW, the reason I've included the user ID" Don't you realize it's a *session* variable so it's already on the server?

Comment: You should probably read the PHP documentation along side any tutorials. They’re great for “heres a solution” but in order to understand it, the documentation is there to tell you everything about it. As mentioned above, you could of easily read the global variable session documentation to understand it would be accessible from the server and has no absolutely no need to be in the client-side - nothing stops someone creating a request using someone else's “user ID” here and since they follow a bigint pattern, it would be easily guessable.

Comment: if error == 0, it means the file is ok. You can read more about file error value here https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php . I think you should change elseif($originalFileError === 0) to elseif($originalFileError !== 0)

Comment: Thanks folks.  Problem solved.  It was the "elseif($originalFileError === 0){" pointed out by Your Common Sense, plus a misnamed function lower down.  I'll sort out that user ID thing now too.  Thanks very much for the tips.

Comment: Also you have typo in function uniqueid() , it should be uniqid()

Comment: Dika, yep, that also.  I also wrote the mysqli_stmt_execute as mysqli_stmt_exec.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo You have written twice as much code as you need. For a beginner this is too much and for a production code you should never write such code. The tutorial you are using while not utterly terrible, does not teach you how to program in PHP properly. Please find a better one, that teaches PDO